# Multiple MySQL insert from PHP data get dynamically from ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, transactions, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert multiples values that I get from ajax form. Something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hashtag1
    [1] => Hashtag2
    [2] => Hashtag3
    [3] => Hashtag4
)
```

Then I get an photo in the request and id from the user owner of this photo.

I have 3 tables that will receive inserts, and a lot of them. Because I need to insert once in photo table, that is the photo that I'm inserting and user owner id, and save the id of this insert for the next steps. After that i need to insert all hashtag, one for each value from array, in this case would be something like this:

```
Insert into hash_tag (`hash_tag_name`) values ("hashtag1"),("hashtag2"), etc.
```

I need save all of the id of this rows because now i will insert in table photo_tiene_hashtag the id_photo to each hashtag that i created.

This will be somthing like:

```
Insert into photo_tiene_hashtag(`id_photo`,`id_hash_tag`) values (idPhotoThatIShouldHaveSaved, idHashtagThatIShouldHaveSaved1), (idPhotoThatIShouldHaveSaved, idHashtagThatIShouldHaveSaved2),
(idPhotoThatIShouldHaveSaved, idHashtagThatIShouldHaveSaved3),
etc.
```

[image]

Don't know how to approach this challenge, probably I must do an beginTransaction() in php and start doing little query, don't know, all this must be in a transaction because I need to be secure that all steps pass correctly.

Sorry about my english.

Cheers!

Comment: If you need to get the ID of the added row, you can only insert one row at a time.

Comment: So you need to do the inserts in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Barmar you will create an array and then do the inserts in foreach saving with SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() the id of the inserts?

Comment: You already have an array that you show at the top of the question. Loop over that array, insert the hashtag, then insert into photo_tiene_hashtag with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the values.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, use a Javascript =>

`var form = document.getElementById("#imageform");`
then create a new form data object in javascript and send it to a php file using ajax, eaither javascript AJAX or using Jquery.
`var formdata = new FormData(form);`
send this using 
`http.open("post", "insert.php", true);`
`http.send(formdata);`
in your php file, use =>
`if(isset($_FILES['user_image'])){`
`echo var_dump($_FILES['user_image']['name']);`
`}`
form here you may proceed to upload the image files to your local server and insert image name and id into the database, for the id you may use a $_SESSION['username'] or pass some sort of id in the java-script script. 
and post it together with the current request like this. =>

`http.open("post", "insert.php?user_id=" + user_id, true);`
`http.send(formdata);`

Comment: that's not my problem,I have all information in php get from the client via ajax, but i need to insert all this data step by step getting id references to this inserted objects in a transaction, and i'm stuck to do. I'm trying to do that @Barmar says in the comments section.